# Method call from string variable

Tags: ruby

I want to replace the below (non DRY) code:

```
dir = value > node.data ? "right" : "left"

if value > node.data
  if node.right.nil?
    node.right = Node.new(value)
  else
    insert(value, node.right)
  end
else
  if node.left.nil?
    node.left = Node.new(value)
  else
    insert(value, node.left)
  end
end
```

with something like this:

```
dir = value > node.data ? "right" : "left"
if node.dir.nil?
  node.dir = Node.new(value)
else
  insert(value, node.dir)
end
```

`Node` is a `struct` defined like so:

```
Node = Struct.new(:data, :left, :right)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a struct, you can use `[:left]` or `[:right]` instead of `.left` and `.right`.

Therefore, you can

```
dir = value > node.data ? :right : :left
if node[dir].nil?
  node[dir] = Node.new(value)
else
  insert(value, node[dir])
end
```